# Replace semicolon in Microsoft JSCRIPT

Tags: jscript, jscript.net, jscript-10

I need to remove semicolon from a string in microsoft **JSCRIPT**.

```
    var Test="{abcdef};"
```

I need to remove the semi colon from the string Test. but it is throwing errror. 
I am using the following two ways to remove ";" from string

```
1)  var reg= new RegExp(";", "g")
    var Test=Test.replace(reg,"")



2)     var Test= Test.replace(/;/g,"");
```

Any Help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: 1) What does the error say? 2) Is it JScript for Windows Script Host (.js files run using wscript/cscript) or JScript.NET (compiled)?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var Test="{abcdef};"
```

creates a new string variable `Test`. To change its value and assign the result to the 'same' variable, write

```
Test=Test.replace(reg,"")
```

not

```
var Test=Test.replace(reg,"")
```

which will clobber `Test` before the .replace method is executed.

Evidence:

```
JScript 10.0.30319
% var t = "a;b;c;"
a;b;c;
% var t = t.replace(/;/g, "")
Error: Object required
% var t = "a;b;c;"
a;b;c;
% t = t.replace(/;/g, "")
abc
```

(This is JScript.NET 10.0.30319; same results for WSH JScript 5.7.16599)